# Add char to the array elements

Tags: perl

Is there any easier way to add char to the beginning and end of array elements in perl.

`Ex:my  $str ='table1,table2,table3'`

`my @arry = split (/,/,$str)`

I like the output should look like

`'table1','table2','table3'`

So it can be used in sql query

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
join(',', map "'$_'", @arry)
```

is what you are asking for.

But it's much better to use placeholders:

```
my $str = 'table1,table2,table3';
my @arry = split(/,/, $str);
if (@arry) {
    my $query = 'select * from tablename where colname in (' . join(',',('?') x @arry) . ')';
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $sth->execute(@arry);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Used the placeholders as suggested by you.

Comment: just be careful of empty arrays...unfortunately, `colname in ()` is not valid SQL

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to use DBI (https://metacpan.org/module/DBI) to work with your database, it can do it for you if you use placeholders in your queries, so that you don't have to quote values.

For example, if you want to insert something into a table:

```
    $dbh->do("INSERT INTO table VALUES(?, ?, ?)", undef, @arry) 
        or die $dbh->errstr;
```

where `@arry` is an array containing exactly 3 values to be inserted into a table.

More on this can be found here https://metacpan.org/module/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values